# Extracting coefficients from nested list of models via plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I have a nested list of models that I want to extract coefficients from, then create a data frame where each row also contains the name of the list elements where that model was stored.  I was wondering if there was either a plyr function that already handles nested lists, or just generally a cleaner way of accomplishing the task.

For example:

```
### Create nested list of models

iris.models <- list()
for (species in unique(iris$Species)) {

iris.models[[species]]<- list()

for (m in c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length")) {

    iris.formula <- formula(paste("Petal.Width ~ ", m))
    iris.models[[species]][[m]] <- lm(iris.formula
                                      , data=iris
                                      , subset=Species==species)

    } # for m

} # for species 

### Create data frame of variable coefficients (excluding intercept)

irisCoefs <- ldply(names(iris.models)
             , function(sp) {
              ldply(iris.models[[sp]]
                    , function(meas) data.frame(Species=sp, Coef=coef(meas)[-1])
            )})
colnames(irisCoefs)[colnames(irisCoefs)==".id"] <- "Measure"
irisCoefs
```

This code yields a data frame like:

```
  Measure      Species          Coef
1 Sepal.Length setosa     0.08314444
2 Sepal.Width  setosa     0.06470856
3 Petal.Length setosa     0.20124509
4 Sepal.Length versicolor 0.20935719
5 Sepal.Width  versicolor 0.41844560
6 Petal.Length versicolor 0.33105360
7 Sepal.Length virginica  0.12141646
8 Sepal.Width  virginica  0.45794906
9 Petal.Length virginica  0.16029696
```

While my code works, the way I ended up doing it seems a little inelegant, and I'm wondering if I could simplify this further (or generalize it for other cases):

My issues are:

Working with the nested lists seemed to be a bit tricky.  In the outer ldply call I had to use the names of the list items, but in the inner one I got the .id column added "for free".
I couldn't figure out an easier way to access the name of the list elements inside the function called.

Nor was I able to change what column name from ".id" within the second ldply function call itself.  So I ended up adding the colnames statement afterwards.

Is there a way to make my code more straightforward within the plyr way of doing things?

I don't know if this helps clarify my intent, but I imagined the code looking something like:

```
ldply(iris.models, .id.col="Species", function(sp) ldply(sp, .id.col="Measure", function(x) data.frame(coef(x)[-1])))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to lselzer and nograpes for their suggestions to solve my problem.  I should have been more specific that for the actual situation I'm dealing with, the models already exist in the nested list, and are not something I need or want to recreate.  My question is just about walking through the nested list, extracting coefs into a data frame, and attaching the names of the list elements on the path to each model as additional columns.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

The plyr aproach:

```
#Melt the predictor variables
iris_m <- melt(iris[, -4], id.vars = "Species")
#Insert the dependant variable
iris_m$Petal.Width <- rep(iris$Petal.Width, 3)

#Make the models divide by species and variable
models <- dlply(iris_m, .(Species, variable), 
                function(x) lm(Petal.Width ~ value, data = x))
#Get the coefficients as a nice data.frame
ldply(models, function(x) coef(x)[-1])

     Species     variable      value
1     setosa Sepal.Length 0.08314444
2     setosa  Sepal.Width 0.06470856
3     setosa Petal.Length 0.20124509
4 versicolor Sepal.Length 0.20935719
5 versicolor  Sepal.Width 0.41844560
6 versicolor Petal.Length 0.33105360
7  virginica Sepal.Length 0.12141646
8  virginica  Sepal.Width 0.45794906
9  virginica Petal.Length 0.16029696
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the required format, but this would work with base functions.

```
m=c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length")
do.call(rbind,
    by(iris,iris$Species,
      function(x) sapply(m, 
        function(y) coef(lm(paste('Petal.Width ~',y),data=x))) [2,]
   ) 
)

           Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
setosa       0.08314444  0.06470856    0.2012451
versicolor   0.20935719  0.41844560    0.3310536
virginica    0.12141646  0.45794906    0.1602970
```